# Querying Kafka Offsets from Flink Savepoint

Tags: apache-flink

Can I somehow find out which offsets the Kafka consumers of my Flink job were the exact moment I took a savepoint? I assume I could hack up something using the [state processor api](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/libs/state_processor_api.html), peering into [the internal state of the Kafka consumer](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/2b8b670ec0f10b909f7420bd000de09d8209f92d/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka-base/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java#L860-L861). But I'd like to know whether I've missed a nicer way, which doesn't rely on implementation details.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of would be to extend the Kafka connector so that it logs the offsets when taking a snapshot.

Comment: I love that idea, but there is one boulder-sized grain of salt: `@Override public final void snapshotState` :( https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/2b8b670ec0f10b909f7420bd000de09d8209f92d/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka-base/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java#L893, same for `notifyCheckpointComplete`. There aren't any other functions I could overwrite, are there?